# ruby remove item from array based on another array

Tags: ruby

i have two data,

```
{:date=>"2015-09-23", :time=>["13:30"]}
{:date=>"2015-09-23", :time=>["12:00"]}
...more
```

and i try to remove this from

```
{:date=>"2015-09-21", :time=>["12:00", "12:30", "13:00", "13:30", "14:00", "14:30"]}
{:date=>"2015-09-22", :time=>["12:00", "12:30", "13:00", "13:30", "14:00", "14:30"]}
{:date=>"2015-09-23", :time=>["12:00", "12:30", "13:00", "13:30", "14:00", "14:30"]}
{:date=>"2015-09-24", :time=>["12:00", "12:30", "13:00", "13:30", "14:00", "14:30"]}
```

and the output i hope can get

```
{:date=>"2015-09-21", :time=>["12:00", "12:30", "13:00", "13:30", "14:00", "14:30"]}
{:date=>"2015-09-22", :time=>["12:00", "12:30", "13:00", "13:30", "14:00", "14:30"]}
{:date=>"2015-09-23", :time=>["12:30", "13:00", "14:00", "14:30"]}
{:date=>"2015-09-24", :time=>["12:00", "12:30", "13:00", "13:30", "14:00", "14:30"]}
```

i was try

```
removeAry.each do |b|
  if b[:date] == "2015-09-23"
    puts b[:time].to_s.delete("13:30")
  end
end
```

do have any better idea ?

Comment: I think you can always make life much easier if you always consider how to store your data according to you application needs. For example, if you have a an array of hashes as such: [{:"2015-09-21" => ["12:00", "12:30", "13:00", "13:30"]}. In this case you can traverse through you structure using array index and then grap your hash using key,value pairs. Key being the day, and value would be an array of time stamps.

Comment: because this data is created by different user and time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here's what I would do:

```
require 'set'

to_delete = [
  {:date=>"2015-09-23", :time=>["13:30"]},
  {:date=>"2015-09-23", :time=>["12:00"]}
]

data = [
  {:date=>"2015-09-21", :time=>["12:00", "12:30", "13:00", "13:30", "14:00", "14:30"]},
  {:date=>"2015-09-22", :time=>["12:00", "12:30", "13:00", "13:30", "14:00", "14:30"]},
  {:date=>"2015-09-23", :time=>["12:00", "12:30", "13:00", "13:30", "14:00", "14:30"]},
  {:date=>"2015-09-24", :time=>["12:00", "12:30", "13:00", "13:30", "14:00", "14:30"]}
]

# convert to_delete array to a hash { "2015-09-23" => #<Set: {"13:30", "12:00"}> }
# we use Set here to store only unique time values
to_delete_as_hash = to_delete.reduce({}) do |acc, item|
  acc[item[:date]] ||= Set.new
  acc[item[:date]] += item[:time]
  acc
end

filtered = data.map do |item|
  # skip this item if there's no need to process this date
  next item unless to_delete_as_hash[item[:date]]
  # subtract to_delete values from current item[:time] values
  item[:time] -= to_delete_as_hash[item[:date]].to_a
  item
end

p filtered
```

Output:

```
[
    {:date => "2015-09-21", :time => ["12:00", "12:30", "13:00", "13:30", "14:00", "14:30"]},
    {:date => "2015-09-22", :time => ["12:00", "12:30", "13:00", "13:30", "14:00", "14:30"]},
    {:date => "2015-09-23", :time => ["12:30", "13:00", "14:00", "14:30"]},
    {:date => "2015-09-24", :time => ["12:00", "12:30", "13:00", "13:30", "14:00", "14:30"]}
]
```

Comment: one more tricky question.

how add condition, if [to_delete] data, no time, just date, need delete that date from data. i'm try modify code now, if you have any advance how to make it, please kind let me know. thanks you so much for your help.

Comment: It is not clear from your comment what input and output you want to achieve. Could you update your question with examples, just as you did the first time? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over how your data is represented then you might consider simplifying your data as such:

The data you want removed

```
{:"2015-09-23" => ["12:00", "13:30"]}
```

Data to be removed from

```
[{:"2015-09-21" => ["12:00", "12:30", "13:00", "13:30", "14:00", "14:30"]},
 {:"2015-09-22" => ["12:00", "12:30", "13:00", "13:30", "14:00", "14:30"]},
 {:"2015-09-23" => ["12:00", "12:30", "13:00", "13:30", "14:00", "14:30"]},
 {:"2015-09-24" => ["12:00", "12:30", "13:00", "13:30", "14:00", "14:30"]}]
```

The output you want achieved

```
[{:"2015-09-21" => ["12:00", "12:30", "13:00", "13:30", "14:00", "14:30"]},
 {:"2015-09-22" => ["12:00", "12:30", "13:00", "13:30", "14:00", "14:30"]},
 {:"2015-09-23" => ["12:30", "13:00", "14:00", "14:30"]},
 {:"2015-09-24" => ["12:00", "12:30", "13:00", "13:30", "14:00", "14:30"]}]
```

By doing this you can now:

```
target = {:"2015-09-23" => ["12:00", "13:30"]}
input = [{:"2015-09-21" => ["12:00", "12:30", "13:00", "13:30", "14:00", "14:30"]},
     {:"2015-09-22" => ["12:00", "12:30", "13:00", "13:30", "14:00", "14:30"]},
     {:"2015-09-23" => ["12:00", "12:30", "13:00", "13:30", "14:00", "14:30"]},
     {:"2015-09-24" => ["12:00", "12:30", "13:00", "13:30", "14:00", "14:30"]}]

input.each do |hash|
  hash.each do |key, value|
    if key == target.keys[0]
      target.values.each do |t_value|
        hash[key].delete(t_value)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please let me know if this doesn't fit your solution so I can enhance the answer. Thanks.

Comment: thanks, but i can't change the data format.

and i try too many time, each time they delete all date time, for example, if i need delete "2015-09-23" "13:00",

return will delete all date "13:00"

Answer (score 0):

## First define your test data

```
data = [{:date=>"2015-09-21", :time=>["12:00", "12:30", "13:00", "13:30", "14:00", "14:30"]}, {:date=>"2015-09-22", :time=>["12:00", "12:30", "13:00", "13:30", "14:00", "14:30"]}, {:date=>"2015-09-23", :time=>["12:30", "13:00", "14:00", "14:30"]}, {:date=>"2015-09-24", :time=>["12:00", "12:30", "13:00", "13:30", "14:00", "14:30"]}]

to_delete = {:date=>"2015-09-23", :time=>["13:30"]}
```

## Main code

```
data.select{|x| x if x[:date] == to_delete[:date]}.each{|x| x.delete(to_delete[:time])}
```

You can also store to_delete in array and iterate over it.

Comment: Why not `data.select{|x| x[:date] == to_delete[:date]}`? Select only cares if return value of a block is truthy, or am I wrong?

Comment: data.select{|x| x if x[:date] == to_delete[:date]}.each{|x| x.delete(to_delete[:time])}

this not work, but 

data.select{|x| x if x[:date] == to_delete[0][:date]}.each{|x| x.delete(to_delete[0][:time])}

why ?

Answer (score 0):

have a try:

```
removeAry.map { |h| h[:date] == "2015-09-23" ? (h[:time].delete("13:30");h) : h }
```

or:

```
def removeAry.function(date, time)
  self.map { |h| h[:date] == date ? (h[:time].delete(time);h) : h }
end

removeAry.function("2015-09-23", "13:30")
```

Comment: if have data with different date, like:
{:date=>"2015-09-26", :time=>["12:00"]}

 this not work...

Comment: @user7331you can define a method, date and time as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I have rewrite your code as following

```
data = [{:date=>"2015-09-21", :time=>["12:00", "12:30", "13:00", "13:30", "14:00", "14:30"]}, 
        {:date=>"2015-09-22", :time=>["12:00", "12:30", 13:00", "13:30", "14:00", "14:30"]},
        {:date=>"2015-09-23", :time=>["12:00", "12:30", "13:00", "13:30", "14:00", "14:30"]},
        {:date=>"2015-09-24", :time=>["12:00", "12:30", "13:00", "13:30", "14:00", "14:30"]}]
```

And Function to manipulate hash

```
def output_hash(data, p_date="2015-09-23", p_time="13:30")
    output = data.collect do |key, value|
      if key[:date] == p_date
         key[:time].delete!(p_time) if key[:time].include?(p_time) 
         time =  key[:time]
         key.delete(:time)
         key.merge!(:time => time)
       else 
         key
       end
    end
    return output
end
```

will generate following `output`

```
 [{:date=>"2015-09-21", :time=>["12:00", "12:30", "13:00", "13:30", "14:00", "14:30"]}, 
  {:date=>"2015-09-22", :time=>["12:00", "12:30", "13:00", "13:30", "14:00", "14:30"]},
  {:date=>"2015-09-23", :time=>["12:00", "12:30", "13:00", "14:00", "14:30"]},
  {:date=>"2015-09-24", :time=>["12:00", "12:30", "13:00", "13:30", "14:00", "14:30"]}]
```

Comment: how it work if have another date and another time ? like :
{:date=>"2015-09-24", :time=>["14:30"]}

Comment: very simple you have to pass two params `p_date` and `p_time`, then use that into the function with rap a method name. See the edited answer rape with a method.

Answer (score 0):

```
hash = [
    {:date => "2015-09-21", :time => ["12:00", "12:30", "13:00", "13:30", "14:00", "14:30"]},
    {:date => "2015-09-22", :time => ["12:00", "12:30", "13:00", "13:30", "14:00", "14:30"]},
    {:date => "2015-09-23", :time => ["12:00", "12:30", "13:00", "13:30", "14:00", "14:30"]},
    {:date => "2015-09-24", :time => ["12:00", "12:30", "13:00", "13:30", "14:00", "14:30"]}
]

comparables = [
    {:date => "2015-09-23", :time => ["13:30"]},
    {:date => "2015-09-23", :time => ["12:00"]}
]

hash.each do |new_hash|
  comparables.each do |comparable|
    if new_hash[:date] == comparable[:date]
      new_hash[:time] = new_hash[:time] - comparable[:time]
    end
  end
end

puts hash
```

Output

```
user@ubuntu:~$ ruby test.rb 
{:date=>"2015-09-21", :time=>["12:00", "12:30", "13:00", "13:30", "14:00", "14:30"]}
{:date=>"2015-09-22", :time=>["12:00", "12:30", "13:00", "13:30", "14:00", "14:30"]}
{:date=>"2015-09-23", :time=>["12:30", "13:00", "14:00", "14:30"]}
{:date=>"2015-09-24", :time=>["12:00", "12:30", "13:00", "13:30", "14:00", "14:30"]}
```